# jQuery ajax parameters not being passed to php as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following javaScript code:

```
const getReport = {
    jobID: $('#jobID').val(),
    startDate: $('#summaryStart').val(),
    endDate: $('#summaryEnd').val(),
    tableType: 'Summary',
};

$.ajax({
    url: "php/reports.php",
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "application/json",
    data: function (d) {
        return JSON.stringify(getReport);
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response["tableColumns"].substring(0, 4) === "<h4>") { //if html returned here no detail query
        } else {
            $('#summaryTable').DataTable({
                select: {
                    sytle: 'single',
                    items: 'row'
                },
                data: response["tableData"], columns: response["tableData"],
                dataSrc: ""
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And in my php code I have the following (to test values coming accross):

```
$rawJson = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $rawJson;
return;

$parms = json_decode($rawJson, true);
$jobId = $parms["jobID"];
```

The code as stated above the XLR value from Chrome's developer tools is blank.  If I run with this code instead:

```
$rawJson = file_get_contents("php://input");
// echo $rawJson;
//return;

$parms = json_decode($rawJson, true);
$jobId = $parms["jobID"];
```

I get:

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null at the statement:  $jobId = $parms["jobID"];

Note: when I get the warning message, javascript executes my success: routine, but the response appears to be null or blank.

I do a similar thing with `fetch` in another part of the app and it works.  I could probably switch to that method, but would like to know why my jQuery call does not work.

Comment: what does `$rawJson` echo?

Comment: I added the code that creates getReport;

$rawJson echoes the empty string.

I will look into Barmar's second comment.  This may be my answer.

Thanks to Barmar and Nadir for the quick responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` option can't be a function. So this:

```
    data: function (d) {
        return JSON.stringify(getReport);
    },
```

should be:

```
    data: JSON.stringify(getReport),
```

Answer (score 2):

The `data` parameter of $.ajax does not take a function it takes a PlainObject or String or Array. Also dataType for JSON is `json` not the json content type `application/json`.

```
const getReport = {
            jobID: $('#jobID').val(),
            startDate: $('#summaryStart').val(),
            endDate: $('#summaryEnd').val(),
            tableType: 'Summary'};

$.ajax({
    url: "php/reports.php",
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(getReport),
    success: function (response) {
        if (response["tableColumns"].substring(0, 4) === "<h4>") { //if html returned here no detail query
        } else {

            $('#summaryTable').DataTable({

                select: {
                    sytle: 'single',
                    items: 'row'
                },
                data: response["tableData"], columns: response["tableData"],
                dataSrc: ""
            });
        }
    }
});
```